# the routes change but the pages are not shown in my react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, bootstrap-5

i   just  used  a Navbar from bootstrap and  i added my  links of  components  , i used  to react-router-Dom ,  the  path is  working  but  the pages are not  changed , should  i  change  something  in my Navbar ? it's  from bootstrap 5  , the  conatian of  components  are not  shown .

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route , Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import About from './screens/About';
import Contact from './screens/Contact';
import traditions from './screens/Traditions';
import Histoire from './screens/Histoire';
import Monuments from './screens/Monuments';

function App() {
  return (
   
    <>
<Router>
<Navbar/>
<Routes>
     <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}/>
     <Route exact path="/about"  component={About}/>
     <Route exact path="/contact"  component={Contact}/>
     <Route exact path="/traditions"  component={traditions}/>
     <Route exact path="/histoire"  component={Histoire}/>
     <Route exact path="/Monuments"  component={Monuments}/>
     </Routes>
     </Router>
    </>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        
        <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Products" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Products
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/monuments">monunments</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/traditions">traditions</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/histoire">histoire</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>   
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using version 6 `react-router-dom`, you should use `Switch` instead of `Routes`

```js
<>
  <Router>
    <Navbar/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      <Route exact path="/traditions" component={traditions}/>
      <Route exact path="/histoire" component={Histoire}/>
      <Route exact path="/Monuments" component={Monuments}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</>
```

But if you are using version 6, your code should look like this:

```js
<>
  <Router>
    <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
      <Route path="/traditions" element={<traditions />}/>
      <Route path="/histoire" element={<Histoire />}/>
      <Route path="/Monuments" element={<Monuments />}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</>
```

Comment: i'm using  version 6 and it still not  working ,  i think its  ok  with  component , the  route change  but  the page  no , it  still empty

Comment: @YassineEssid Your component does not seem to have a problem, did you use `element` instead of `component`? Because in version 6 the `component` has been changed to `element` and `exact` is not needed because it detects by `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

use `/` on the last. when react router encounter `/` it will render your home page

```
<>
  <Router>
    <Navbar/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      <Route path="/traditions" component={traditions}/>
      <Route path="/histoire" component={Histoire}/>
      <Route path="/Monuments" component={Monuments}/>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 the `Route` component API changed significantly. There is no longer `component` and `render` props, they were replaced by the `element` prop that takes a ***JSX literal*** instead of a reference to a React component or a function that returns JSX.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path="/traditions" element={<Traditions />} />
  <Route path="/histoire" element={<Histoire />} />
  <Route path="/Monuments" element={<Monuments />} />
</Routes>
```

Side Note: In `Navbar` component change all the `"class"` attributes to `"className"`. If the raw anchor `<a />` aren't working try using the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route , Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import About from './screens/About';
import Contact from './screens/Contact';
import Traditions from './screens/Traditions';
import Histoire from './screens/Histoire';
import Monuments from './screens/Monuments';

function App() {
  return (
   
    <>
<Router>
<Navbar/>
<Routes>
     <Route exact path="/"  element ={<Home/>}/>
     <Route exact path="/about"  element ={<About/>}/>
     <Route exact path="/contact"  element ={<Contact/>}/>
     <Route exact path="/traditions"  element ={<Traditions/>}/>
     <Route exact path="/histoire"  element ={<Histoire/>}/>
     <Route exact path="/Monuments"  element ={<Monuments/>}/>
     </Routes>
     </Router>
    </>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

### First Solution and Best Solution:

1. If you use are using React Router 5.3.x, check whether it is 5.3.3 in your package.json file.
2. If it is not 5.3.3 uninstall the last version then install the bug-free version which has been resolved by John and updated in version 5.3.3.

- npm uninstall -S react-router-dom
- npm install -S react-router-dom@5.3.3

### Second Solution:

React has launched its StrictMode in its latest update.
you can see it in an index.js file

> index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

So here your React Router is in the child component. And we have to make it a parent component.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<BrowserRouter>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

### Third Solution:

Remove the Strict mode from the index.js file

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
);
```