# React-router-Link not working->On clicking The link The URL is updated as per but page is not rendered, I have already put exact in route

Tags: react-router

the code goes as below,

```js
    import './App.css';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
    import Home from './Pages/Home';
    import About from './Pages/About';
    import Notfound from './Pages/Notfound';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li><Link to="/" >Home</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>                          
              </ul>
          </nav>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route path='/about' component={About} />
              <Route component={Notfound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link tag inside BrowserRouter changes only the URL, but doesn't render the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832720/link-tag-inside-browserrouter-changes-only-the-url-but-doesnt-render-the-compo)

Comment: I have issue with my dependencies.After updating to react-router-dom@6 , my problem got resolved. While using version--@6 of react-router-dom, I just changed Switch with Routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things needs to be fixed,

1. `Route` should be defined inside `Routes`.

```js
<Routes>
  <Route ... />
  ...
  ...
</Routes>
```

2. Latest `react-router-dom` API has changed `Route` accepts component in the `element` prop not `component`.

```js
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Dependency versions

```
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
```

[image: Edit cranky-goldberg-x06efn]

Comment: @Raj Das, check this out !!

Comment: can you share the dependencies? specifically versions of react,react-router and react-router-dom. I think my problem lies there.

Comment: I have updated in the answer. Can you check and share your dependencies as well? You can recreate the issue by forking the code sandbox I have published and put it in the question.

Comment: i have updated the dependencies,now its working. thanks!!!