# React-Router "Link" changes url, but won't trigger render of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've torn this example down to barebones to make it as simple as possible.

I have a `HomePage` with a Link to `PostPage`

The Link in `HomePage` wraps a `Post` component that just says "post" (was originally a list)

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sara-ugx9e6?file=/src/App.js)

I've looked up more than a few similar questions and somehow none of them seem to help.

Using `react-router-dom: ^5.3.0`

*App.js*

```js
import './App.css';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'

import HomePage from './pages/HomePage'
import PostPage from './pages/PostPage'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/post' component={PostPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*HomePage*

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Post from '../components/Post'

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link to='/post'>
                <Post />
            </Link>
        )
    }
}

export default HomePage
```

*Post*

```js
const Post = () => <div>Post component</div>
export default Post
```

*PostPage*

```js
const PostPage = () => <div>Post Page</div>
export default PostPage
```

*history*

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug somewhere other than your code.. I downgraded to React 17 from 18 and it began working as intended. It's possible that React Router v5 does not support React 18.

Comment: Wow, I've actually been going crazy. I just downgraded React and ReactDOM to 17 and it triggered a re-render. Although then it gave me some "legacy" error and this "Target container is not a DOM element." error which keeps coming up on CodeSandbox no matter what I do.

Comment: You'll need to change the root rendering code to match the 17 style.

Comment: Correct. Man, I hope someone else finds this useful because I was losing my mind. Kind of unfortunate that they don't work together. Maybe I'll just migrate everything to the new versions. Really appreciate the help, though!

Comment: Actually, I think that I can keep the latest versions, but continue using the older root render. Seems to work still.

Comment: I'd probably recommend updating to RRD v6 when possible. The longer you hold out the harder it will be to update in the future (most times)

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870

Comment: Yeah, as someone in the comments of that thread pointed out, having the history object is somewhat essential, but I'm sure there are workarounds.

Comment: React 18 and React Router Dom 5 can, and do, work together. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857