# React Router V5 - link component is not switching routes (but an anchor link works)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I've got a create react app with react router v5 and the following setup:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import EmailRep from "./components/EmailRep";
import WebAuthN from "./components/WebAuthN";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <EmailRep />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/webauthn">
            <WebAuthN />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In my `EmailRep` component, if I attempt to link to the `WebAuthN` route, it does nothing

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function EmailRep() {
  return <Link to="/webauthn">WebAuthN</Link>;
}
```

But this works:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function EmailRep() {
  return <a href="/webauthn">WebAuthN</a>`;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like it should work can you reproduce in a sandbox?

Comment: I copy your code in a sandbox and works perfectly with `Link` component, I don't see some error, do you trying reset your server?

Comment: Is the URL updating when using the `Link` component? Are you using React 18 by any chance? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese - yes! I think this is the issue - I'm using React 18 and React Router V5 and I don't think the URL is updating. Please feel free to list this as an answer and I'll test and accept.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if this is your case because you didn't share those components code but maybe you forgot to import the `Link` module from `react-router-dom`,

Try inserting this snippet at the top of your `EmailRep` and `WebAuthN` modules:

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Hope this helps!

Comment: revised post to clarify that I am including this