# React Router 5.0 Link in one component not going to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a small website for a friend. I have two components in the App.js. They look like separate pages as one is a homepage with links to to an artist page where artwork will be shown.

The issue I have is the menu on the Gallery page. It's not returning to the home page. Below is the code. I'm only putting in the ones that matter...

```
App.js
import './assets/css/4/w3.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Homepage from './components/Homepage.js'
import Artists from './components/Artists.js'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Homepage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/artists/:id">
            <Artists />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


Homepage.js

import '../assets/css/homepage.css';
import Nav from './Homepage/Nav.js'
import Header from './Homepage/Header.js'
import About from './Homepage/About.js'
import Menu from './Homepage/Menu.js'
import Contact from './Homepage/Contact.js'
import Footer from './Homepage/Footer.js'

const Homepage = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Nav />
            <Header />
            <About />
            <Menu />
            <Contact/>
            <Footer />
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Homepage;

Menu.js (This is on the homepage and calls up the Gallery page)

import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TabNavItem from "./TabNavItem";
import TabContent from "./TabContent";
 
const Menu = () => {

    let homepageData = require('./homepage.json');

    let widthStyle = {
        width: "100%"
    }

    let maxWidth1000 = {
        maxWidth: "1000px"
    }

    const coffeecup2 = require("../../assets/images/coffeecup2.jpg");

    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("Art");

    return (  
        <div className="w3-container" id="menu">
            <div className="w3-content" style={{maxWidth: "700px"}}>
                <h5 className="w3-center w3-padding-48"><span className="w3-tag w3-wide">THE MENU</span></h5>

                <div className="w3-row w3-center w3-card w3-padding">
                    <TabNavItem title="Art" id="Art" activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab}/>
                    <TabNavItem title="Poetry" id="Poetry" activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab}/>
                    <TabNavItem title="On Stage" id="On_Stage" activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab}/>
                    <TabNavItem title="Music" id="Music" activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab}/>
                </div>
            
                <div className="w3-container w3-padding-48 w3-card menu-card"> 
                    <TabContent id="Art" activeTab={activeTab}>
                        {homepageData.filter(data => data.section === 'art').map(filteredHomepage => (
                            <div key={filteredHomepage.id}>
                                {/* <h5 className="artistLink">{filteredHomepage.name}</h5>
                                <p className="w3-text-grey">{filteredHomepage.homepage_description}</p> */}
                                {/* <Link to="/artist"> */}
                                <Link to={ `/artists/${filteredHomepage.id}`}>
                                    <h5 className="artistLink">{filteredHomepage.name}</h5>
                                    <p className="w3-text-grey">{filteredHomepage.homepage_description}</p>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </TabContent>

                    <TabContent id="Poetry" activeTab={activeTab}>
                        {homepageData.filter(data => data.section === 'poetry').map(filteredHomepage => (
                            <div key={filteredHomepage.id}>
                                <h5><a className="artistLink" href={filteredHomepage.link}
                                    target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{filteredHomepage.name}</a></h5>
                                <p className="w3-text-grey">{filteredHomepage.homepage_description}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))} 
                    </TabContent>

                    <TabContent id="On_Stage" activeTab={activeTab}>
                        {homepageData.filter(data => data.section === 'on_stage').map(filteredHomepage => (
                            <div key={filteredHomepage.id}>
                                <h5><a className="artistLink" href={filteredHomepage.link}
                                    target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{filteredHomepage.name}</a></h5>
                                <p className="w3-text-grey">{filteredHomepage.homepage_description}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))} 
                    </TabContent>

                    <TabContent id="Music" activeTab={activeTab}>
                        {homepageData.filter(data => data.section === 'music').map(filteredHomepage => (
                            <div key={filteredHomepage.id}>
                                <h5><a className="artistLink" href={filteredHomepage.link}
                                    target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{filteredHomepage.name}</a></h5>
                                <p className="w3-text-grey">{filteredHomepage.homepage_description}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))} 
                    </TabContent>
                </div>

                <img src={coffeecup2} style={{...widthStyle, ...maxWidth1000}} className="w3-margin-top" alt="Coffee Cup"/>
                <p style={{maxSize: "9px"}}>Photo by Kari Shea on Unspash</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Menu;

Artist .js (The other page that calls the Gallery.js)

import '../assets/css/artist.css';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import SidebarMenu from './Artists/SidebarMenu.js';
import Gallery from './Artists/Gallery.js';
import About from './Artists/About.js';
import Contact from './Artists/Contact.js';
import Footer from './Artists/Footer.js';
import useFetch from "./useFetch.js";

const Artists = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data:artist, isPending, error } = useFetch("http://localhost:8000/artist/" + id);

    return (
        <div className="w3-light-grey">
            { error && <div> {error} </div> }
            { isPending && <div>Loading...</div> }

            <SidebarMenu />
            <Gallery />
            {artist && <About artist={artist}/>}
            <Contact />
            <Footer />
        </div>
      );
}
 
export default Artists;

The side menu (notice the side menu to go home)

import { useState } from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

const SidebarMenu = () => {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleDrawer = (isOpen) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
          return;
        }
        setOpen(isOpen);
      };

    return ( 
        <div className="w3-light-grey">
            <header className="w3-container w3-top w3-white w3-xlarge w3-padding-16">
                <span className="w3-left w3-padding" id="artist_name">Angela Cali</span>
                <span className="w3-right w3-button w3-white" onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}>☰</span>
            </header>
            {/* Sidebar/Menu */}
            <Router>
                <nav className={'w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-animate-right w3-top w3-text-light-grey w3-large nav-lg' + (isOpen ? ' open' : '')} id="mySidebar">
                    {/* This is going to toggle the link to open and close the menu */}
                    <div className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16" onClick={toggleDrawer(false)}>CLOSE</div>
                    <HashLink to="#gallery" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">GALLERY</HashLink>
                    <HashLink to="#aboutMe" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">ABOUT ME</HashLink>
                    <HashLink to="#contactMe" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">CONTACT ME</HashLink>

                    <div className="hr"></div>

                    <div className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">HALA FAISAL</div>
                    <div className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">LESLEY A. POWELL</div>
                    <div className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">TERRI SUESS</div>
                    <div className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">YUHO</div>
                    <div className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">ANGELA CALI</div>

                    <div className="hr"></div>

                    <Link to="/" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16">TERRI CAFE HOME</Link>
                </nav>
            </Router>

            {/* Overlay effect when opening sidebar on small screens */}
            <div className={'w3-overlay w3-animate-opacity' + (isOpen ? ' open' : '')} title="close side menu" id="myOverlay"></div>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default SidebarMenu;

The Gallery.js (which I'm still working on. It doesn't have the data import yet)

import { useState } from 'react';

const Gallery = () => {
    const artistPath = "angelacalie";
    const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

    const handleMouseOver = () => {
        setIsHovering(true);
    }

    const handleMouseOut = () => {
        setIsHovering(false);
    }

    return ( 
        <div className="w3-main w3-content main-content__artist">
            <div className="w3-row w3-grayscale-min mb-3rem gallery" id="gallery">
                <div className="col-container">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="img__container">
                            <img src={window.location.origin +'/img/' + artistPath + "/bold_purpose.jpeg"} className="width-100" 
                                onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
                                alt="Need a title/description" />
                            {isHovering && (
                                <div className="img__description">Wax pastel on paper, 17" x 14", Angela Cali. 2010</div>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src={window.location.origin +'/img/' + artistPath + '/moonlight_domain.jpeg'} className="width-100" alt="Untitled_1.  Watercolor on paper. 8.5” x 11”. Terri Suess. 2012." />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.3.1_roundabout.jpg" className="width-100" alt="Untitled_3. Watercolor on paper. 3” x 8.5”. Terri Suess. 2012." />
                    </div>
            
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.4.1_morningemerges.jpg" className="width-100" alt='Disappering Piers. Ink on paper.  4” x 5”. Terri Suess, 2010.' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div className="col-container">
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src={window.location.origin +'/img/' + artistPath + "/bold_purpose.jpeg"} className="width-100" alt="Need a title/description" />
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.2.2_goldengardens.jpg" className="width-100" alt="Untitled_1.  Watercolor on paper. 8.5” x 11”. Terri Suess. 2012." />
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.3.2_buttercup.jpg" className="width-100" alt="Untitled_3. Watercolor on paper. 3” x 8.5”. Terri Suess. 2012." />
                    </div>
            
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.4.2_humphrey.jpg" className="width-100" alt='Disappering Piers. Ink on paper.  4” x 5”. Terri Suess, 2010.' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div className="col-container">
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src={window.location.origin +'/img/' + artistPath + "/bold_purpose.jpeg"} className="width-100" alt="Need a title/description" />
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.2.3_construction38st_2.jpg" className="width-100" alt="Untitled_1.  Watercolor on paper. 8.5” x 11”. Terri Suess. 2012." />
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.3.3_snowywoods.jpg" className="width-100" alt="Untitled_3. Watercolor on paper. 3” x 8.5”. Terri Suess. 2012." />
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="col">
                        <img src="artwork/3.4.3_razorridge.jpg" className="width-100" alt='Disappering Piers. Ink on paper.  4” x 5”. Terri Suess, 2010.' />
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Gallery;
```

Again, thank you for any help you can gear me in. If anyone needs a github, I could load it up.

Donna

Comment: What versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed and used? If using React 18 and any pre-v5.3.3 version of `react-router-dom` there was an issue with the `React.StrictMode` component. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857

Comment: Hi. I'm using  5.3.3 for react-router-dom and 2.4.3. react-router-hash-link...so this may not answer my question. Thank you though for your response.

Comment: Hi. I just tried to remove the strict and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, none of the solutions for the above stackoverflow didn't work at all. And I'm using React 18.1.0 and Router DOM 5.3.3. The only thing I can do is try this with Router 6.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I would also hold off on trying to upgrade to RRDv6 since `react-router-hash-link` package hasn't been updated to work with it AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `SidebarMenu` component is rendering an additional `Router` and this *inner* router is handling the links below its context. The main *outer* router isn't aware of any routing/navigation actions that were handled by the more deeply nested router.

You need only one router to provide a routing context to an entire app.

For this reason you need to remove the nested `BrowserRouter` that `SidebarMenu` is rendering.

```
const SidebarMenu = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div className="w3-light-grey">
      ...

      {/* Sidebar/Menu */}
      {/* REMOVE THE ROUTER THAT WAS HERE WRAPPING `nav` ELEMENT */}
      <nav
        className={...}
        id="mySidebar"
      >
        {/* This is going to toggle the link to open and close the menu */}
        ...
        <HashLink
          to="#gallery"
          className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16"
        >
          GALLERY
        </HashLink>
        <HashLink
          to="#aboutMe"
          className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16"
        >
          ABOUT ME
        </HashLink>
        <HashLink
          to="#contactMe"
          className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-center w3-padding-16"
        >
          CONTACT ME
        </HashLink>

        ...

        <Link to="/" className="...">
          TERRI CAFE HOME
        </Link>
      </nav>

      {/* Overlay effect when opening sidebar on small screens */}
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-5-0-link-in-one-component-not-going-to-another-component]