# React Router isn't rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react router v5.2.0 and my code doesn't render anything. Would really appreciate some help. No errors are being shown.

Index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
   </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
  <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/player/:id" component={Player}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            videos: []
        };
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App App-header">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.state.videos.map(video => 
                        
                        <div className="col-md-4" key={video.id}>
                            <Link to={`/player/${video.id}`}>
                                <div className="card border-0">
                                    <img src={`http://localhost:4000${video.poster}`} alt={video.name} />
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <p>{video.name}</p>
                                        <p>{video.duration}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any other details . Please let me know where the error might be.

Comment: What ***specific*** versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed? You can check by running `npm list react react-router-dom` in the terminal at the project's root directory. If using `react-router-dom@5.2.x` and `react@18` *and* rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857

Comment: Did you check your browser console? is there any error there?

Comment: @DrewReese frontend@0.1.0 /Users/anirudhsathiya/Desktop/video-streaming/frontend

├─┬ react-router-dom@5.3.3
│ ├─┬ react-router@5.3.3
│ │ ├─┬ mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped **invalid: "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from node_modules/react-router/node_modules/mini-create-react-context**



This is the output of npm list. I'm little new to react. How can I fix the invalid error?

Comment: Share your imports in `App.js` file.

Comment: @SujithSandeep
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

import Footer from "./components/footer"
import img from "./media/goldengate.jpeg";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";


import Home from './components/Home';
import Player from './components/Player';

Comment: Okay... Check whether you have imported  your `App.js` properly in your `index.js` file...

Comment: Or else edit and add your `index.js` and complete `app.js` file in your question itself...

Comment: @SujithSandeep added index.js in the post. Let me know if you want to see app.js too

Comment: Add complete app.js too...

Comment: Also check whether `this.state.videos` state is empty...

Comment: Ok, looks like you've actually RRDv5.3.3 installed, which is ok with Reactv18. When, or where, is the `this.state.videos` state in `Home` ever populated? Is this the complete code? Can you share a [mcve] for all relevant code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue it seems is with the `mini-create-react-context` package, it's deprecated and isn't compatible with React 18. See [source](https://github.com/StringEpsilon/mini-create-react-context/blob/master/package.json#L32).

> ```
> "peerDependencies": {
>   "prop-types": "^15.0.0",
>   "react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0"
> },
> ```

This package appears to only exist to polyfill (*"ponyfill"*) the React Context API, which to be honest isn't something I believe ever needed to be polyfilled.
If you aren't using it (*and I don't suspect you need it*) then remove it from your project's dependencies.

Run: `npm uninstall -s mini-create-react-context`

This will remove the dependency *and* update your package.json file.

Search your code for any `mini-create-react-context` imports

```
import createReactContext from 'mini-create-react-context';
```

and replace them with vanilla React `createContext`

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
```