# Buttons not working when using reactjs and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I wrote my first app using nodejs,reactjs and spring using [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-react-crud) tutorial and all went fine except for the buttons that are not working as expected because when I click on them, the link is updated in the browser address but the page is not loaded until I press F5 to reload.

Is hard to explain without an image so I attached a print screen with some text.

So I can add customers, delete and edit... but after every click on a button, I must press F5 to actually load the destination page. I tried this in Chrome, Edge and Opera and in all browsers the behaviour is the same.

This seems to be very basic but I don't know what to search on google to fix it, I tried to search documentation about the button tag but in everything I read I can't even find the attributes listed in the tutorial.

The button syntax is "<Button size="sm" color="primary" tag={Link} to={"/clients/" + client.id}>Edit" and attributes like "tab" and "to" don't seem to be documented in the reactjs documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching I found the answer here:

[Link tag inside BrowserRouter changes only the URL, but doesn't render the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832720/link-tag-inside-browserrouter-changes-only-the-url-but-doesnt-render-the-compo)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Link in react router
and also check you api if their syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the useHistory hook with Button onClick. Seems like there is no **to** prop in reactstrap documentation. You need to convert your container component using the Button in to functional component though.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push(`/clients/${client.id}`);
  }

  return (
    <Button size="sm" color="primary" onClick={handleClick}>Edit</Button>
  );
}
```