# How to make your React page load on clicking a button with a <Link> element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, hyperlink

```
<Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
```

I wrote this ,when i click on the button

the url is updated but the page is not loading ,i have to refresh the page to load in to the page i desired
and also I am using react-router-dom@5.2.0 to use Switch .

I need to load the site to the path that i specified as i click the button

Comment: Post your code for App.js, or wherever you're doing your routing.

Comment: Please do try to post a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857