# Error while use react-router-dom to rout one comp0nent to another on click to using history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I create a basic log page in react where on login it will redirect me to the next component
I use react-router v5.3
it is showing an error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
how can I resolve this error

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {useHistory,} from 'react-router-dom';


    export default function Loginpage() {
    const history = useHistory();

    //set the initial sate for the inputs
    const [username, setusername] = useState('');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');

    //function to handle form submission
    const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();// prevent from refreshing the page

        //checck the user name and password 
        if (username === 'employee' && password === 'emp123'){
            history.push('./components/JobFindPage');
            alert('hii');
        }
        else  if (username === 'employer' && password === 'emr123'){
            history.push('/CreateJobPage');
            alert('hii');
        }
        else{
            alert ('wrong username or password')
        }
    }


    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit = {handleFormSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Username :
                    <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)} /> <br />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Password :
                    <input type="text" value={password} onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)} /> <br />
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Log IN</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

I expected that using history push(/component) will redirect me to that component

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the `useHistory` hook and usage. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: can you tell me how can i do it

Comment: How to create a codesandbox? Click that link, create a new workspace using the React template, and start copy/pasting your code. It's an online IDE that is effectively a VsCode clone. Once your code is in place, please double-check the package dependencies to ensure they match what you are using locally.

Comment: here is every thing that I did     https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-leaf-3tnumh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

The app is missing rendering a router to provide a routing context and `history` object.

Import a router and wrap the `App` component.

Example:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Since you are using `react@18` and rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component you'll also want to bump to ***at least*** `react-router-dom@5.3.3` to resolve a [compatibility issue between React 18 and RRDv5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857).

The `Login` component also should navigate to paths the app is rendering routes for. `history.push("./components/JobFindPage");` will incorrectly append `"/components/JobFindPage"` to the end of the current URL path.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function LoginPage() {
  const history = useHistory();

  //set the initial sate for the inputs
  const [username, setusername] = useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = useState("");

  //function to handle form submission
  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent from refreshing the page

    //checck the user name and password
    if (username === "employee" && password === "emp123") {
      history.push("/JobFindPage"); // <-- fix this path
      alert("hii");
    } else if (username === "employer" && password === "emr123") {
      history.push("/CreateJobPage");
      alert("hii");
    } else {
      alert("wrong username or password");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <label>
          Username :
          <input
            type="text"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)}
          />{" "}
          <br />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password :
          <input
            type="text"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)}
          />{" "}
          <br />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Log IN</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-khayyam-zj0t3l]