# Link in React doesn't forward to a new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

My question might seem stupid because I don't have enough background in React JS.
Consider the code :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Header/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/project/:id" exact component={ProjectTasksPage}/>
                        <Route path="/" exact/>
                        <Route path="/users" exact component={UsersPage}/>
                        <Route path="/projects" component={ProjectsPage}/>
                        <Route path="/tasks" component={TasksPage}/>
                    </Switch>
                    <ProjectsPage/>
                    <Link to="/project/1">Link</Link>
                    <Footer/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>


        );
    }
}
```

why is the link in react created correctly, but the browser does not go to the page?

---

Comment: What specific versions of React and React-Router-Dom are installed and used, and are you rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857

Comment: I'm truly grateful for your help! Thank you!