# React Router: Routes not updating content without manual page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm facing an issue with React Router where routes are not updating without a page refresh. I'm using BrowserRouter in my React app. The navigation works, but the content doesn't update until I manually refresh the page. I've tried using HashRouter as a workaround, but I'd like to understand why BrowserRouter is not working as expected. I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../Pages/Home/Home";
import Authors from "../Pages/Authors/Authors";
import Magazine from "../Pages/Magazine/Magazine";
import Podcast from "../Pages/Podcast/Podcast";

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/magazine" component={Magazine} exact>
          <Magazine />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/authors" exact component={Authors} />
        <Route path="/podcast" exact component={Podcast} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import Layout from "./Components/Layout/Layout";
import "./index.css";
import "./Assets/fonts/GeneralSans/Fonts/WEB/fonts/GeneralSans-Medium.ttf";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Layout />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Layout.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "../../Routes/Routes";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import "../../index.css";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        render={(props) => (
          <div>
            <Header {...props} />

            <Routes />

            <Footer />
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Don't use the `component` prop ***and*** provide children components. Can you [edit] to clarify what isn't loading when navigating? What *specific* versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are you using, and are you rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese the content doesn't update when I click on links in the Navbar. The URL in the address bar changes, but the page content remains the same unless I manually refresh the page

Comment: And the answers to my others questions?

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated my question check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest `<BrowserRouter/>`. Remove the `<BrowserRouter/>` component from the `Routes` component.  A working example:

`Routes.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div>home</div>;
const Magazine = () => <div>Magazine</div>;
const Authors = () => <div>Authors</div>;
const Podcast = () => <div>Podcast</div>;

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact>
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/magazine" component={Magazine} exact />
      <Route path="/authors" exact component={Authors} />
      <Route path="/podcast" exact component={Podcast} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

`Layout.tsx`:

```
import './style.css';
import Routes from './Routes';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = (props) => {
  console.log('header props: ', props);
  return (
    <header>
      <Link to="/home">home</Link>
      &nbsp;
      <Link to="/magazine">magazine</Link>
      &nbsp;
      <Link to="/authors">authors</Link>
      &nbsp;
      <Link to="/podcast">podcast</Link>
    </header>
  );
};

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        render={(props) => (
          <div>
            <Header {...props} />
            <Routes />
            <footer>footer</footer>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ewlvgf?file=src%2FRoutes.tsx)