# 'BrowserRouter' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type 'typeof e' is not a valid JSX element type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am currently doing a pet project of mine with both client and server folders and a tsconfig.json file outside both folders
Within my client folder, I have a App.tsx file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const App: React.FC = () => {
...
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    ...
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

But I am getting the follow error
'BrowserRouter' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'typeof e' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type 'typeof e' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
Type 'e' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)

My client folder only has typescript files (even in the subfolders) and my tsconfig.json is as below

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "allowJs": true,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "../client",
        "rootDir": "./servernew",
        "types": ["node", "react"],
        "noEmit": true,
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./client/src/@types", "./client/@types", "./client/src/components/Auth/@types"]
  },
      "include": ["./client/*", "./servernew/*"],
      "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
    }
```

Please send help!

I have tried checking my react-router-dom and react versions

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

I have also tried using `BrowserRouter as Router` and moving my `BrowserRouter` to my index.tsx but both still gives me the same error.

I have deleted my node_modules folder and installed it again but still face the same issue.

Comment: What version (if any) of `@types/react-router-dom` do you have in package.json? Version 5 of react-router-dom does not come with types built in.

Comment: Install the appropriate `@types/react-router-dom` dependency so the types can be correctly inferred/used, and then apply the fix from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857) to address the issue you'll likely face with using React 18 and React-Router-DOM@5.2.

Comment: You guys were right. I had to add the below to my package.json
  ```"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }```,